# CycleGAN vs. AutoEncoder for transforming sketches into images

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoder, gan, image-preprocessing, processing

I'm playing around with the use of deep learning on images and done quite works : colorizing black and white images for example, or maybe fixing old damaged photos.

Today I want to tackle a new problem, concerning the conversion of sketches into real look like images as shown in the figure.

[image: input is a sketch and the output should be an image corresponding to the input]

Performing this could be done in various ways. I want to know if it is correct to think of **CycleGANs** for this task, since in truth they are not made trivially for that, and the **pros** and **cons** for **CycleGANs** and **AutoEncoders** for such task.

**PS:** Generating data is not a big deal for me, I have already a large database, and the right scripts to do the conversions in the both directions.